# Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable-mdpi/1.jpg')

Tags: java, android, xml

This is the code I'm using

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable-mdpi/1.jpg"
    tools:context="project.ImageDriveStore.MainActivity" >
```

and I have also stored the "1.jpg" in `drawable-mdpi` folder,
but still I'm getting the following error:

```
"Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable-mdpi/1.jpg')"
```

Thanks in advance for your valuable suggestions

Comment: remove "-mdpi" and ".jpg, use @drawable/1

Comment: The Android resource system does not care about file extensions, which is why you should remove the ".jpg". It does not matter if you drop in a png or a jpg, they all work.

As far as the removal of -mdpi: these different drawable folders exist to allow the app to load the best version of your drawable depending on which device your app is run.  So you can have the same drawable in different sizes in all these folders, and just use "drawable" as a reference so the app loads the correct one on runtime without you needing to worry about the correct path for that specific file.

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
android:background="@drawable-mdpi/1.jpg"
```

to

```
android:background="@drawable/1"
```

`mdpi, ldpi, xdpi, xxdpi` etc folders are created to manage screens with different dpi(s). By simply pointing to `@drawable` will allow `Android` system to detect which image to show on particular device.

Comment: Thanks @Opiatefuchs, I was about to write :)

Answer (score 0):

We can not use drawable name simple numeric value.So use any text name of drawable then it will work fine for you.
don't use 1.png ,use any text name like red_button.png
 and use your drawable name like

```
android:background="@drawable-mdpi/red_button"
```

Comment: it´s correct what You´ve said about the file endings but this example is also wrong because it uses @drawable-mdpi. Look Jibrans answer, You should correct Yours to avoid OP from beeing confused..